# Is there a way to check in the dashboard if I am using a separate installation or WordPress.com?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting

Is there a way to check within the dashboard to know if I am using a separate installation or WordPress.com? I am working for a client and logged into their account and they themselves are not sure. Is there anything I can do to confirm or check?

Comment: Go to WordPress.com and use your credentials to log in.  If it doesn’t work, you’re on a self hosted/.org.

Answer (score 0):

I Googled this for you and found this:

How Do I Know If I Have WordPress .Com Or .Org?

1. Go to your WordPress login dashboard by typing your site’s domain into a browser followed by /wp-login.php
2. Your WordPress login dashboard will appear. Hover your mouse over the WordPress logo in the center (or your own logo if you customized it).
3. & Voila, the bottom left corner of the browser will tell you if you have wordpress.org or wordpress.com installed!

Source: https://sugarandcode.com/know-if-i-have-wordpress-org/

Basically:

- if the link is not available or does not work - you are using wp.com

Update - I added a screen grab of wordpress.com login - note also the URL https://wordpress.com/log-in

[image]

Comment: I did see this link. In my Dashboard there is no WordPress logo in the center. Maybe I am misunderstanding the link.

Comment: Or, maybe that is the right answer to your question?

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting you. I do not see how it answers my questions as I do not see any logo in the center nor do I see anything on the bottom left corner.

Comment: Does the link work - domain.com/wp-login.php ?